# Different setter and getter for django model field

Tags: python, django

I have a null boolean mysql field in django:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    ...
    status = models.NullBooleanField()
```

However, when I call it, I want it to return the following:

```
@property
def status(self):
    return "Pending" if self.status is None else "Paid" if self.status == 1 else "Failed"
```

What would be the correct way to (1) set the data as a boolean; but then (2) when calling it receive the text? For example:

```
>>> invoice = Invoice()
>>> invoice.status = True
>>> invoice.save()
>>> invoice.status
"Paid"
```

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be to rename the property a text field such as:

```
@property
def status_text(self):
    return "Pending" if self.status is None else "Paid" if self.status == 1 else "Failed"
```

Another option would be to use the following approach:

```
class User(models.Model):
    _status = models.NullBooleanField(db_column='status')

@property
def status(self):
    return "Pending" if self.status is None else "Paid" if self.status == 1 else "Failed"

@first_name.setter
def status(self, value):
    self.status = status
```

However, the second approach is not really a fix-all, as you won't be able to do something like:

```
User.objects.filter(status=True)
```

This is why I'd suggest the more explicit first approach.